# Contract method works on local but not on testnet

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, erc-721, kovan

The following method, which works perfectly fine on my local ganache.

```
function someMethod() external view
    returns (
        bool someValue,
        uint256 lastIndex,
        uint256 totalTokens
    ) {
    address owner = msg.sender;
    uint256 tokensForOwner = ERC721.balanceOf(owner);

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokensForOwner; i++) {
        uint256 tokenId = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, i);
        if (someValue[tokenId] > 0) {
            return (true, i, tokensForOwner);
        }
    }

    return (true, tokensForOwner);
  }
```

However when deployed to the Kovan testnet I get the following error

```
data: "Reverted 0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002a4552433732313a2062616c616e636520717565727920666f7220746865207a65726f206164647265737300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
message: "VM execution error."
```

I did some checking by deploying multiple versions it seems the line at fault is

```
        uint256 tokensForOwner = ERC721.balanceOf(owner);
```

For which I tried `ERC721.balanceOf(owner);` and `balanceOf(owner);`.

Would anyone have any idea on why this happens and what is the solution?

Comment: Could you provide the whole code ?